# Class of functions that the Fourier inversion holds

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

The following is from Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*:

> For each $a>0$ we denote by ${\mathcal F}_a$ the class of all functions $f$ that satisfy the following two conditions:
>
> 1. The function $f$ is holomorphic in the horizontal strip
>      $$
>    S_a=\{z\in{\Bbb C}:|Im(z)|<a\}
>    $$
> 2. There exists a constant $A>0$ such that
>      $$
>    |f(x+iy)|\leq\frac{A}{1+x^2}\quad\text{for all}\quad x\in{\Bbb R}, |y|<a.
>    $$
>
> Denote by ${\mathcal F}$ the class of all functions that belong to ${\mathcal F}_a$ for some $a$. The the Fourier inversion holds in this class.

Here are my **questions**:

- Is there a name for this class?
- Does it have anything to do with the Schwartz space on which the
  Fourier transform is a linear isomorphism?

Comment: I don't think there's a canonical name for this class, nor any relation to the Schwartz space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, this is done on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122807/class-of-functions-that-the-fourier-inversion-holds/122836#122836).